# Random large number calculator shows nothing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate the sum of two random long numbers. However, it does’t seem to produce anything.

This is my code:

```
var input1 = prompt("One random number (must be whole and one digit)");
var input2 = prompt("Another random number");
var num1 = Math.random(parseInt(input1)) * 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
var num2 = Math.random(parseInt(input2)) * 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
while (num1 > 10) {
    num1 /= Math.random(10);
}
num1 * 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
while (num2 > 10) {
    num2 /= Math.random(10);
}
num2 * 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
var sum = num1 + num2;
document.write(sum);
```

It should show a very large random number, but it just seems to show nothing. Why is this? Is there something wrong with my code or is my device just slow, meaning that I give up before it is finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.random` does not take any argument and always returns a number between 0 and 1, so right now `num1 /= Math.random(10);` actually increases num1 for each iteration. The same goes for num2. So both loops never end.

If you want to return a random number between 1 and 10, you should use `Math.random() * 9 + 1`.